# Factorial equation

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find all nonnegative integer solutions to $x!^2=z!$. Intuitively, I think the solutions are the trivial ones with $x=0,1$ and $z=0,1$. I'm not sure how to show that there is no more solutions.

Comment: Are there any given criterion, such as, _x_|_z_ or _x_ does not divide _z_? I was just thinking about applying [Hansel's lemma](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf) or [LTE](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) (I don't know why). If this comment seems a secondary discussion, please ignore and don't flag. Instead, you can ask me to delete this comment (I am sorry to say this twice today. In fact, I am a new user too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every prime factor of $x!^2$ appears to an even power.

By Bertrand's postulate we can find a prime factor $p$ of $z$ greater than $\frac z2$. Then the exponent of $p$ in $z!$ is one.

Comment: This is also the solution I came up with. Is there a solution that does not involve Bertrand's postulate?